# How this URL will be decoded - Confusion in basic Http Get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, url, encoding, parameter-passing

Basically I need to pass three paramaters to a http as get. Here are the parameters

```
param1 = 3
param2 = 454
param3 = http://localhost:3000/another_test?another_param=4&another_param2=978
```

This transforms to

```
http://localhost:3000/test?param1=3&param2=454&param3=http://localhost:3000/another_test?another_param=4&another_param2=978
```

I am just confused whether the URL formed is correct or not. Will this work or is there anyother way to do this. I am using Rails. I did a decode and clicked on the link and I still see the above URL coming. Will this work on the receiever side, meaning will it be decoded as I had intended.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work as long as you url encode the params. In that case the `&` and `?` will be transformed, making it possible for Rails to differentiate between the query string parameters and the query string delimiters.

To ensure that it is encoded you can use `Rack::Utils.escape` or `Hash#to_query`.

Answer (score 2):

This will be decoded as:

```
param1=3
param2=454
param3=http://localhost:3000/another_test?another_param=4
another_param2=978
```

You need to encode param3, or at minimum replace the ampersands in it with the correct URL encoding, in order for it to match back up to your input parameters.